# Может ли сервер выдержать посетителей?

Tags: веб-сервер

Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос, я меня есть VPS вот с такими характеристиками 
`Процессор Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2386 SE 1203.175 Mhz 
Оперативная память 3145728 kB
Размер дискового пространства 10240 Mb
Средняя загрузка 0.05 0.06 0.01` 
Может ли он выдержать человек 500 в день, которые будут активно использовать mysql (Вся работа будет проводится с помощью AJAX)

Comment: Мало конкретики...

Если запросы простые, и серверные скрипты простые - скорее сможет...

А если у вас запрос выполняется 1 минуту - то врятле...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

500 юзеров в день - это не много и сервак выдержит легко при условии, что в коде все в порядке и нет запросов, как правильно заметили в коментах, минута+ Удобней мерять запросами в секунду: в вашем случае 500 юзеров в день - это 24 часа * 60 мин * 60 сек / 500 = 1 запрос в почти 3 мин - это копейки (при условии, что юзер сделает по запросу). А вот если все эти юзеры будут *одновременно* онлайн и начнут делать *активно* разные запросы, то это уже совсем другая нагрузка.

Comment: @wind смысл моей идеи в том, что юзер загрузит страницу только один раз и вся дальнейшая информация будет поступать через AJAХ и у юзера будет обновляться инфа ( и он будет посылать запросы тоже по аякс) то есть серваку нужно будет дать пользователю страницу и потом он будет с юзером общаться по аяксу, через аякс будут поступать данные для добавления инфы в бд и взятия её оттуда.

Comment: ИМХО для таких целей и при таком железе - php сервак не лучшее решение

Comment: @AlexWindHope ну так подскажите..что будет лучше.

Comment: Разница не большая, как будет происходить обмен инфой клиента с сервером, по средствам аякса или нет - это в любом случае запрос на сервер, который ему нужно обработать, также он может, как вы упомянули, тянуть инфу из БД, а это обращение к БД, которая может стоять на другом сервере, запрос может быть не простым и тянуть МНОГО данных, а это время, хадержки и тд и тп. Для примера: mssql server 2008 загибается при 40000 уникальных запросов в несколько минут (мб пол часа), причем запрос не тяжелый. Сервер же держит эту нагрузку без проблем и он не намного лучше по параметрам, указанного вами.

Comment: Пример для IIS 7.5 и windows server 2008. По поводу пхп ничего сказать не могу.

Comment: И еще раз повторю: 1000 зареганых юзеров и 100 онлайн - это копейки, которые держат серваки обычно без проблем. (бывают конечно исключения и специфичные штуки)

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть уже готовое приложение под задачу, вы можете замерить генерируемую приложением нагрузку. Замеры делаются минимум 3 типов.
 1. Без нагрузки вообще.
 2. Со средней нагрузкой.
 3. С большой нагрузкой.
Замерам будут подлежать следующие параметры
 1. Время отклика.
 2. Загрузка ЦП.
 3. Использование оперативной памяти.
 4. Количество обращений к диску.
Данные полученные с помощью синтетических тестов с такими условиями позволят приблизительно оценить необходимые ресурсы. Данные тесты необязательно проводить на боевом сервере. Достаточно хорошей десктопной машины. При тестировании желательно заранее определить узкое место в системе или приложении, чтобы в случае возникновения нехватки производительности знать, куда в первую очередь копать.